# Overlapping Bootstrap Columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, dynamic-columns

I have a problem with my columns overlapping when I resize my site. The site works perfectly when it's desktop size, but if I drop it down to tablet or below, my columns overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the height of the sections to the min-width property rather than just width